# Problem with overwriting function.json in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I would like to ask you about solution to my current problem.
First of all, I would like to emphasize that it is not duplicate even though quite similar articles can be found on stackoverflow.

Behavior of my azure function:

When configuration property "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" is set to 1, function is available in "Functions" and I get the following information:

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a
> package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file
> and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.

Basing on stackoverflow articles changing the property value to 0 should make function.json editable. However I get a second information:

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you have source
> control integration enabled.

What is more function **not loger exists in "Functions"** and function.json is not more available on Kudu's debugconsole in wwwroot/sites.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the first information, you should set 0 for WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE.

For the 2nd information:

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you have source
> control integration enabled.

It means that you have setup continuous deployment for your function app. You should disable it by the following steps:

Nav to azure portal -> your function app -> Deployment Center, then click the disconnect button(it might be a little different if the source is different). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Remember to enable continuous deployment again after you make some changes to your function app.

Comment: So @Ivan Yang your approach allows me to remove a warning message from "Functions" but as I mentioned it was not a main problem. The main problem was that after changing value to 0 I can't see any function in "Function" (look at screen").

Comment: @azuremycraj, how did you deploy your azure function? if you deploy it by using [run from package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package), then you cannot see the function even if WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0. You should consider re-deploy this function, and NOT using run from package.

Comment: Hey, I am using an zip artifact from CI/CD

Comment: hi, can you please first set website_run_from_package to 0，then re-deploy function?

Answer (score 1):

As your app is deployed from github pipelines you should change properties in source code and deploy new version.
If you will change WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 0, all properties will be overwritten during next deployment.